# Coverting a list of array of lists of lists into dataframe

Tags: python, arrays

I need help in conversion of a list of array of lists of lists into a dataframe

my data is something like this

```
[array([[ 0.01568627,  0.01568627,  0.01176471],
   [ 0.01176471,  0.01176471,  0.01176471],
   [ 0.01176471,  0.01176471,  0.01176471],
   ..., 
   [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.05098039],
   [ 0.04705882,  0.05098039,  0.04705882],
   [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.04705882]]), array([[ 0.01568627,  0.01568627,  0.01568627],
   [ 0.01176471,  0.01568627,  0.01176471],
   [ 0.01176471,  0.01568627,  0.01568627],
   ..., 
   [ 0.05490196,  0.05098039,  0.05098039],
   [ 0.05098039,  0.05490196,  0.05098039],
   [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.05098039]])
```

When I tried df=pd.DataFrame(lst),it didn't work

I'm trying to read image and put it into a list

My code is something like this

```
for filename in files:
img = misc.imread(filename)
img = img[::2, ::2]
X = (img / 255.0).reshape(-1, 3)
lst.append(X)
```

I get above data when I print lst

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What is the shape of the desired output?

Comment: actually I'm reading images and storing them as a list.My code id something like this for filename in files:
    
    img = misc.imread(filename)
    img = img[::2, ::2]
    X = (img / 255.0).reshape(-1, 3)
    lst.append(X)

Comment: OK but how should the returning DataFrame look like? In this list you have 2 arrays and these arrays are two dimensional. A DataFrame is also two dimensional so for 2 2D arrays, you need to do some reshaping (with multiindex, concat etc.)

Comment: I don't know.I need to plot the dataframe using scatter 2d.when i use 'df=pd.DataFrame(lst)' command I get the following error  'Must pass 2-d input'

Comment: @SHIVAMGOYAL Is it possible that your desired output is a list of DataFrames? It's very hard to understand your target output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider concatenating with `pd.concat()` from a list comprehension. Do note you will lose slight precision of two decimal points to fit `float64` dtype. Below will output a 3-column dataframe:

```
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

lst = [array([[ 0.01568627,  0.01568627,  0.01176471],
              [ 0.01176471,  0.01176471,  0.01176471],
              [ 0.01176471,  0.01176471,  0.01176471],              
              [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.05098039],
              [ 0.04705882,  0.05098039,  0.04705882],
              [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.04705882]]),
       array([[ 0.01568627,  0.01568627,  0.01568627],
              [ 0.01176471,  0.01568627,  0.01176471],
              [ 0.01176471,  0.01568627,  0.01568627],              
              [ 0.05490196,  0.05098039,  0.05098039],
              [ 0.05098039,  0.05490196,  0.05098039],
              [ 0.05098039,  0.05098039,  0.05098039]])]


df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in lst]).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
#            0         1         2
# 0   0.015686  0.015686  0.011765
# 1   0.011765  0.011765  0.011765
# 2   0.011765  0.011765  0.011765
# 3   0.050980  0.050980  0.050980
# 4   0.047059  0.050980  0.047059
# 5   0.050980  0.050980  0.047059
# 6   0.015686  0.015686  0.015686
# 7   0.011765  0.015686  0.011765
# 8   0.011765  0.015686  0.015686
# 9   0.054902  0.050980  0.050980
# 10  0.050980  0.054902  0.050980
# 11  0.050980  0.050980  0.050980
```